# date difference sql

Tags: postgresql

I have dates in 2 tables. Table student is as below:

```
ID|Name|Examdate
1  John 01/10/2015
2  Fred 11/12/2014
```

Table retake as below:

```
ID|RetakeDate
1  02/10/2016
2  05/11/2015
```

So what I am trying to do is create another table where only students who have taken a retake after 12months or more exist. the difference between examdate and retake date needs to be >=12months.

How do I achieve this?

PS: there could be multiple rows in both tables for the same student!